# Clipping Modis ocean color chlor-a data using shapefile in R?

Tags: raster, r, modis, clip

How do I clip Modis ocean color chlor-a data using a shapefile in R?

```
.libPaths("C:/R-packages")
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
setwd("G:/Geoinformatics/Second semester/Spatial Statistics/Spatial_Statistics/Practicals/Practical_3/MOD28_SST_daytime_8day_2017")
getwd()
dir()
#open .nc
nc_open ("G:/Geoinformatics/Second semester/Spatial Statistics/Spatial_Statistics/Practicals/Practical_3/MOD28_SST_daytime_8day_2017/A20170012017008.L3m_8D_SST_sst_4km.nc")

#projection

r2 <- raster("G:/Geoinformatics/Second semester/Spatial Statistics/Spatial_Statistics/Practicals/Practical_3/MOD28_SST_daytime_8day_2017/A20170012017008.L3m_8D_SST_sst_4km.nc",var="sst")
proj4string(r2)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What happens when you run the code that you have presented?

Answer (score 1):

Load vector. Use it to crop and mask:

```
# load vector
shp <- shapefile('path/to/shapefile.shp')

# check if CRS are the same. If not, reproject
if (as.character(crs(shp)) != as.character(r2@crs)){
  shp <- spTransform(shp, CRSobj = r2@crs)
}

# crop and mask
r3 <- crop(r2,shp)
r3 <- mask(r2,shp)
```